# CSS Paint API doesn't work with link <a> elements

Tags: javascript, css, css-houdini, css-paint-api

Didn't find that anyone raised this question here before.

I'm wondering why CSS Paint API  doesn't work with `a` link elements?

---

For example. Here is the working example with `div` element

https://codepen.io/una/pen/xByaoB

And in this one I replaced it with an `a` tag

https://codepen.io/PavelLaptev/pen/jOydKRO

---

And it doesn't matter will you or not add `display: block`. Also, a beautiful carriage is turning into a pumpkin after I add `href`.
And this effect applies in any case where Pain API is used for an `a` + `href` tag .

Thank you

Comment: yes, thank you   @Kaiido

Comment: I've noticed that as well. For me it looks like a browser bug